# as3 vars and packages with same name causing flash builder to throw 3599 error

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder

Just switched to flash builder and working as3 code from flash is throwing lots of 3599 errors:

3599 Definition name is the same as an imported package name. Unqualified references to that name will resolve to the package and not the definition.

I know that this is due to my packages having the same name as class property vars that reside inside the package, but I don't know what the best practice is for resolving these name conflicts. The problem is I like to name packages and variables after classes sometimes. for example:

```
package icon {
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class IconMaker extends Sprite{

    private var icon:Icon;

    public function IconMaker(icon:Icon):void{
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    public function make():void {
        icon.iconButton = new IconButton();
        icon.addChild(icon.iconButton);
    }
}
}
```

So my question is what is the best practice: underscore prefix (_icon) or "my" prefix (myicon) or should I rename the package? or what.

Thank you very much

Comment: Usually, the underscore prefix means that it is aon internal (private or protected) representation of a public property. So  public function set foo(value:String) {_foo=value}. I, personally, resolve these issues by finding a more descriptive name for the variable. For instance, I had a conflict with my service package and a variable called service, and I renamed it to whatThisIsLoadingService.

Comment: in this case there is only one icon class so to qualify it seems unnecessary, but perhaps that is the best option. by the way, it is a private variable so why not underscore?

Comment: If it's a private variable, then great. I didn't notice that you said in your post whether it was or not. I, personally, prefer to have underscores specifically mean "this is private storage for a publically exposed property" (as it seems to have its roots in preventing awkward this.foo=foo), but I know lots of people use it more generally.

Comment: i like your convention if i understand you. you mean "publicly exposed" via get/set methods right?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest renaming the packages. [Naming conventions for packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) are as follows: com.publisher-website.app and then spans to more specific packages like graphics.icons or something like that. The source is for Java but basically the same applies to AS3.

Comment: This has actually fallen out of favor lately, except for library code (where you're sharing with the world and trupeting who wrote it is more important than quickly accessing the Classes you need).

Comment: I didn't think that changing the package hierarchy would have any effect on the name conflict. I am probably wrong...let me check.

Comment: @Amy I didn't know it was out of favor. I always try to name the packages using those conventions. especially in Flash, because swf is really easy to disassemble and if somebody does it, he can see the creator of it. So you as a developer are easy to reach if there's a working opportunity :) Plus, you can still access all the classes easily, what makes it hard? Every IDE generates the import lines for you, so you won't have to write long lines yourself.

Comment: The convention is not for advertisement purpose.  It is a way to avoid conflicts between libraries regardless of how you combine them.

Comment: @FlorianF That's the original purpose of them, agreed. However it doesn't make my point invalid.

Comment: It was more a reaction to Amy who saw it as the only reason.  Yes, attribution of the work is also a valid reason for including your company name in the package names.